# Как изменить иерархию уровней при группировке DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

Предположим есть DataFrame такого вида:

```
samp = pd.DataFrame({'region': ['North','North','South','South','East','East','West','West'], 
                     'store': list('ABCDEFGH'), 
                     'num': 100, 
                     'year':['2020','2020','2021','2021','2021','2021','2020','2021']})
```

```
  region store  num  year
0  North     A  100  2020
1  North     B  100  2020
2  South     C  100  2021
3  South     D  100  2021
4   East     E  100  2021
5   East     F  100  2021
6   West     G  100  2020
7   West     H  100  2021
```

Нужно сгруппировать данные регионов по строкам, и года по столбцам.

Делаю это или через  `pivot_table`  или  `groupby`, что дает одинаковый результат. Примерно так:

```
pd.pivot_table(samp, index='region', columns='year',values=['store','num'],
                   aggfunc={'store': 'count','num':'sum'})
```

```
samp.groupby(['region','year']).agg(
           total_num=("num","sum"), 
           stores=("store", "count")).unstack()
```

Получаем на выходе необходимые данные в таком виде:

```
         total_num      stores     
year     2020   2021    2020 2021
region                             
East      NaN  200.0    NaN  2.0
North   200.0    NaN    2.0  NaN
South     NaN  200.0    NaN  2.0
West    100.0  100.0    1.0  1.0
```

Можно ли как-то изменить порядок группировки (иерархию?), чтобы получить данные в таком виде (то есть сгруппировать столбцы по годам):

```
       2020                2021
values total_num  stores   total_num  stores
region                             
East         NaN     NaN        200.0    2.0
North      200.0     2.0          NaN    NaN
South        NaN     NaN        200.0    2.0
West       100.0     1.0        100.0    1.0
```

В сводных таблицах Excel это делается легким движением мышки, но здесь я никак не могу найти способ вывести данные в таком виде. `swaplevel` по сути ничего не меняет.

Mожно ли как-то это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.swaplevel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) и [DataFrame.sort_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html?highlight=sort_index#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index):

```
res = (samp
       .groupby(['region','year'])
       .agg(total_num=("num","sum"),stores=("store", "count"))
       .unstack()
       .swaplevel(axis=1)
       .sort_index(axis=1))
```

результат:

```
In [60]: res
Out[60]:
year     2020             2021
       stores total_num stores total_num
region
East      NaN       NaN    2.0     200.0
North     2.0     200.0    NaN       NaN
South     NaN       NaN    2.0     200.0
West      1.0     100.0    1.0     100.0
```

Comment: да, то что надо!